# Create a WordPress administrator without access to back-end

Tags: admin, mysql, user-access

My site recently got hacked, and all my admin users lost their administrator level access. But when I access mySQL database, I saw all the users still exist.

How can I create an administrator when I can access the database only?

Comment: Google "wordpress create user in the database". The first three or four results will tell you exactly how to do it.

Comment: @bcorkins We collect canonical answers **here**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Run this script in phpMyAdmin or whatever tool you use to access MySQL:

```
SET @user_login := 'justin_foell';
SET @user_pass := 'Q9xiHgzZ';
SET @user_email := 'justin@9seeds.com';

INSERT INTO `wp_users` 
(`user_login`, `user_pass`, `user_email`, `user_registered`) 
VALUES 
(@user_login, MD5(@user_pass), @user_email, now());

SELECT @user_id := LAST_INSERT_ID();

INSERT INTO `wp_usermeta` 
(`user_id`, `meta_key`, `meta_value`) 
VALUES 
(@user_id, 'wp_capabilities', 'a:1:{s:13:"administrator";b:1;}');

INSERT INTO `wp_usermeta` 
(`user_id`, `meta_key`, `meta_value`) 
VALUES 
(@user_id, 'wp_user_level', '10');
```

Replace the set values at the top for `@user_login`, `@user_pass` and `@user_email` with your own settings. Also, if your WordPress installation uses tables that start with a prefix other than `wp_`, you’ll want to replace that in the table names as well.

From: https://9seeds.com/tech/inserting-yourself-as-admin-into-wordpress/